# Asp.net Core 2 on Azure periodically crash

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

here's my problem:

I ran an asp.net core 1.1  app on as azure webapp for several months without problems. (App currently in development and only used by one testing company)

After upgrading to asp.net core 2 (+ ef core 2) my app crashes every 1 - 1,5 days with very high memory consumption & enourmous "local read bytes" (normal peak = ~8mb, peak as crash happans: >800mb).

As soon as local read bytes increase, memory consumption explodes, and so does av. response time - till no request is answered anymore. Only an app restart helps at this point - app is (why?) not restarted automatically.

So my question: Is there any way I can see what request causes the high local read rate? Or what operation? Or what file is accessed in that time?

By the way: there is no increase in network data out, so this must be some local bug..

Thanks for the help :)

)
[image: (Pic is the relation between normal data read and peak]

Comment: By the way: In Application Insights there is no exception listed, no increase in requests etc...